# Liferay error message does not show file size?

Tags: liferay-6

I used `liferay-ui:error` to display error message when users upload a file:

in action method:

```
SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, UserPortraitSizeException.class.getName());
```

in jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserPortraitSizeException.class %>"
        message="please-enter-a-file-with-a-valid-file-size-no-larger-than-x" />
```

It worked. The message was showed, except the limit size that I set in `portal-ext.properties [users.image.max.size=307200]` does not appear

The message was:

```
Please enter a file with a valid file size no larger than {0}k.
```

Am I missing something? (I am using lifera 6.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to format your message using LanguageUtil.java's utility method . 
I.e.
LanguageUtil.format(themeDisplay.getLocale()," please-enter-a-file-with-a-valid-file-size-no-larger-than-x",Propsutil.get(" users.image.max.size "))

Just another information for language messages having {n}, where n is number.

This is used when you want to have message with some custom dynamic attribute, and you have to provide dynamic attribute as arguments of liferay-ui:message tag.

For Example:

```
<liferay-ui:message key="abc" arguments='<%=new Object[]{"King","Thanks"}%>'/>
```

and in language properties file you have,
abc= You are {0}, {1}

then it will result in message
"You are King, Thanks"

Regards,